# Reading XML with duplicate tags

Tags: python

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

in the above sample XML, in 'web' category there are multiple duplicate tags for 'author'. When I try to read it through the below code, only the first author is extracted but I want to get all 4. How to do so?

```
for book in root.findall('book'):
    title = book.find('title').text
    author = book.find('author')
    year = book.find('year').text
    price = book.find('price').text
    # print(title,author,year,price)
```

Comment: See `.findall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `findall` method to get the complete list of authors and loop through the authors and make a single string out of it.

```
In [02]: for book in root.findall('book'): 
    ...:     title = book.find('title').text 
    ...:     # looping and joining all the authors to make single string
    ...:     author = ', '.join([auth.text for auth in book.findall('author')]) 
    ...:     year = book.find('year').text 
    ...:     price = book.find('price').text 
    ...:     print('title: {}\nauthor(s) :{}\nyear: {}\nprice: {}\n\n'.format(title, author, year, price)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                       
title: Everyday Italian
author(s) :Giada De Laurentiis
year: 2005
price: 30.00


title: Harry Potter
author(s) :J K. Rowling
year: 2005
price: 29.99


title: XQuery Kick Start
author(s) :James McGovern, Per Bothner, Kurt Cagle, James Linn, Vaidyanathan Nagarajan
year: 2003
price: 49.99


title: Learning XML
author(s) :Erik T. Ray
year: 2003
price: 39.95
```